# How should I have flagged this question?

Tags: support, flags

I follow a few tags and try to clean-up questions tagged ADO when really they should be tagged as Azure-DevOps.  In general, if the question is bad I will just flag instead of editing the tags.

In the case of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66847956/perform-the-following-ado-activities-in-your-ado-account-create-a-project-in-yo), I'm really not sure why this question has gotten through two rounds of review: First Post and Flagged review.

[image]

Should I have used a different flag here?  Is this even a valid question?  I've got silver on the tag and I can't parse that there is even a question.  It looks more like a cut/paste of the opening to homework or walkthrough to me.

Comment: Flag it as "Needs details and clarity" there is no question in that question...

Comment: you haven't unlocked close votes yet, but through the flag UI you can choose close reasons over VLQ

Comment: don't worry nobody understands the rules

Comment: The safest option is to just never use Very Low Quality, on either questions or answers. It's completely useless as far as I can tell, any situation where you could use it you could also use a normal close reason that's less likely to be declined (or NAA in the case of answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want to close it. Since you have under 3k reputation, that means you should flag it for closure, which is under the "Needs improvement" option in the flag panel.

[image: Screenshot of the flag dialogue with the radial button for "needs improvement" selected.]

From your question it seems like can be somewhat difficult to recognize as the correct option if it seems like the question is just terrible and not something that can be improved - so I can see why you might not have chosen that option at first.

Comment: That option could perhaps be renamed then.

Comment: Feel free to start a discussion about it - the difficulty is coming up with the correct header that doesn't necessarily require knowing SE jargon - such as understanding what "closing" means.

Comment: or... just make the close dialog available to everyone, but cause it to raise a flag for those who don't have the privilege unlocked. crystal clear

Comment: Only clear if you know what closing is, @KevinB :) Flagging is a concept that's somewhat ubiquitous around the web. Closing can be somewhat confusing to newer users.

Comment: Thanks.  This is helpful.  I think on most of the majority of my other flags I always use something from needs improvement.  Only skimmed the dupe recommendation so far, but it seems like VLQ is just a trap flag.

Comment: All the more reason to introduce them to it, considering new users are the ones most likely to encounter closure,

Comment: @Matt For questions that are still open, you're probably correct. I think there have been discussions about making VLQ a flag for answers only at some point in the past. I can see value in them for closed questions that probably need to be deleted but, in general, they're *most* helpful for answers - and yet, even then, they cause a lot of issues! Our system is a very complex one. :P

Comment: In addition, a "low quality" flag should rarely be used and should only be used as a last resort and is *very* likely to get declined by a moderator.

Comment: @Catija - not sure I get your reasoning - if a person does not know what closing *is*, why do we trust them to make the right choice in the first place? "Duplicates" do not need improvement (there are just that - dupes), so do "community-specific reasons". If you ask me, these options are much more likely to cause confusion to newer users.

Comment: @OlegValter A flag is just a flag. It doesn't actually cast a vote to close but it can mean that a post gets into the close review queue sooner than it might otherwise. That said, it's worth pointing out that our system judges your abilities based on reputation, not knowledge of our system, so that ship, as it were, has already sailed. A 20 k user doesn't necessarily know how to properly close a question while a 200 rep user may.

Comment: @Catija - now I don't follow you even more :) I never referenced rep, only "newer" users, the reasoning applies to anyone without knowledge of the platform, be it 20 or 20K rep (it is also true that the *chance* is higher if the user is newly created). Also, it seems kind of strange to me to defend one shortcoming with another like not being able to judge abilities correctly. Since you also mentioned to Jeanne "feel free to start a discussion about it" that's exactly what we are doing. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] P.s. "it can mean that a post gets into the close review sooner" - exactly the reason why a flagger should know they are going to participate in closing a question and not in an obscure "needs improvement" action. Frankly, the wording is not bad, but it is confusing with the given option list where "duplicate" and "community-specific reason" do not mean "needs improvement" at all.

Comment: @OlegValter The comments on a support question aren't really where that discussion should happen - Comments are just generally a bad place to do this. The invitation was to ask a new question specifically to discuss changing the wording and whatnot.

Comment: @Catija - my initial comment was to address your response to Kevin B ("closing can be somewhat confusing to newer users") with the discussion already happening, didn't get any vibe of starting a new question from that (also it was a discussion question until you edited the tags [not questioning the validity of the edit, though]). Anyways, more on the topic: the point is that the "Question Close Updates" rollout hid what the option actually is about in favour of the intent (making "duplicate" and "community-specific" options out-of-place), and [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] the "needs improvement" name is actually what makes people confused about choosing the correct option (among other reasons) and not not knowing what closure is.